# replace zero with value of an other column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1:

```
    ref   Name   id  Score
  8400   John    0     12
  3840  Peter  414      0
  7400  David  612     64
  5200  Karen    0      0
```

I want to replace 0 in the **id column** with value from **ref column** of the same row So it will become:

```
   ref    Name   id   Score
  8400   John  8400     12
  3840  Peter  414      0
  7400  David  612     64
  5200  Karen 5200      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

via `mask()`:

```
df['id']=df['id'].mask(df['id'].eq(0),df['ref'])
```

OR

via numpy's `where()`:

```
#import numpy as np
df['id']=np.where(df['id'].eq(0),df['ref'],df['id'])
```

Comment: Thanks it works, what if i want to replace 0 with their index?

Comment: @AhmedChater use `df['id']=np.where(df['id'].eq(0),df['ref'],df.index)`

Answer (score 1):

With `loc`, we look at the places in `id` column where it is equal to 0 and put the values from `ref` there (choosing right indices from `ref` happens automatically):

```
df.loc[df.id == 0, "id"] = df.ref
```

to get

```
>>> df

    ref   Name    id  Score
0  8400   John  8400     12
1  3840  Peter   414      0
2  7400  David   612     64
3  5200  Karen  5200      0
```